# uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error

Tags: spring

I am using MyBatis 3.5.1 to update MySQL 5.7, but today the app throw this error:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/wallet/CustomWalletRecordMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.sportswin.soa.wallet.dao.CustomWalletRecordMapper.walletRecordForUpdate-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: set @update_id := 0;         UPDATE wallet_record SET active_num = ifnull(active_num,0) + ?,         id = (SELECT @update_id := id),         remain_num = ifnull(remain_num,0) + ?         WHERE user_id = ?         LIMIT 1;         select                            id, user_id, remain_num, active_num, frozen_num, max_limit_perday, total_limit, money_type,         app_id, created_time, updated_time               from wallet_record where id = @update_id;
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar!/:2.0.2]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar!/:2.0.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.selectOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:159) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar!/:2.0.2]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:89) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:61) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.walletRecordForUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService.updateWalletRecordEnhance(WalletRecordService.java:216) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService.consume(WalletRecordService.java:160) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdf3e4a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.alibaba.druid.support.spring.stat.DruidStatInterceptor.invoke(DruidStatInterceptor.java:72) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58a5717e.consume(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdf3e4a4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.alibaba.druid.support.spring.stat.DruidStatInterceptor.invoke(DruidStatInterceptor.java:72) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.service.impl.WalletRecordService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ec109b4.consume(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController.consume$original$4ZHucCAP(FeignClientWalletRecordController.java:148) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController.consume$original$4ZHucCAP$accessor$Rd8x4Gvy(FeignClientWalletRecordController.java) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController$auxiliary$GpfOaBXZ.call(Unknown Source) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.InstMethodsInter.intercept(InstMethodsInter.java:86) [skywalking-agent.jar:7.0.0]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController.consume(FeignClientWalletRecordController.java) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$968f0238.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d41c2fd.consume(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$968f0238.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.controller.impl.FeignClientWalletRecordController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57d38d6b.consume(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor484.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.handleConnectionException(DruidDataSource.java:1543) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.handleException(DruidPooledConnection.java:133) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledStatement.checkException(DruidPooledStatement.java:77) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.execute(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:502) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor222.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:64) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor230.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.doQuery(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:67) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:108) ~[pagehelper-5.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor229.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper.intercept(OrderByHelper.java:115) ~[orderby-helper-0.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar!/:2.0.2]
    ... 119 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at com.mysql.cj.AbstractQuery.startQueryTimer(AbstractQuery.java:191) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.startQueryTimer(StatementImpl.java:638) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:924) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute$original$lL8bPBbJ(ClientPreparedStatement.java:370) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute$original$lL8bPBbJ$accessor$lxI7mirZ(ClientPreparedStatement.java) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement$auxiliary$NO68xXbZ.call(Unknown Source) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.InstMethodsInter.intercept(InstMethodsInter.java:86) [skywalking-agent.jar:7.0.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3051) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterEventAdapter.preparedStatement_execute(FilterEventAdapter.java:440) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3049) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterAdapter.preparedStatement_execute(FilterAdapter.java:1080) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3049) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.PreparedStatementProxyImpl.execute(PreparedStatementProxyImpl.java:167) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.execute(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:498) ~[druid-1.1.9.jar!/:1.1.9]
    ... 166 common frames omitted
```

I think maybe the SQL is slow and trigger the timeout exception. But when I execute the SQL:

```
set @update_id := 0;
UPDATE wallet_record SET active_num = ifnull(active_num,0) + 1,         id = (SELECT @update_id := id),         remain_num = ifnull(remain_num,0) + 1         WHERE user_id = 1         LIMIT 1;         select                            id, user_id, remain_num, active_num, frozen_num, max_limit_perday, total_limit, money_type,         app_id, created_time, updated_time               from wallet_record where id = @update_id;
```

It is very fast(<100ms).so where is the problem and What should I do to avoid this error? This is my MyBatis timeout config:

```
<setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="5"/>
```